# jQuery UI Autocomplete for Search field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to use JQuery UI Autocomplete for my search field in wordpress but it doesn't work and I got no errors. So I called all needed files like this in my file functions.php :

```
function enqueue_scripts_refonte(){
    $style_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-styles','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-styles' );
    wp_register_script( 'my-autocomplete', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/v3/my-autocomplete.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ), '1.0', false );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-autocomplete', 'MyAutocomplete', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-autocomplete' );

}
```

Always in the same file functions.php :

```
function my_search() {
        $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );
        $suggestions = array();

        $loop = new WP_Query( 's=' . $term );

        while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();
            $suggestion = array();
            $suggestion['label'] = get_the_title();
            $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();

            $suggestions[] = $suggestion;
        }

        wp_reset_query();


        $response = json_encode( $suggestions );
        echo $response;
        exit();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search', 'my_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search', 'my_search' );
```

Then my-autocomplete.js file contains the following script :

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        var term = $("#s").val(); 
        var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=my_search&term="+term;
        $( "#s" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 3
        }); 
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure, but I see your `my-autocomplete.js` file localized but not registered. Also jquery ui automplete requires jquery ui core. I don't see it neither.

Comment: @Neovea Thank you for your response it's registred by this line I think wp_register_script( 'my-autocomplete', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascripts/v3/my-autocomplete.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' ), '1.0', false );

Comment: Ok right, so were is juery ui autocomplete script ?